# Solve equation for z.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I'd like to know how to express the $z = \frac{3}{2}a$ result from the equation below...
I tried to factor or to complete the square, but without success.

$3a^2=8az-4z^2$

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Can you please tell how did you completed the square or tried to factor ?

Comment: What would you have done if it were $3 = 8z-4z^2$?  Now, remember that $3a^2$ is just a number just like $3$ is.  Don't be intimidated by letters.

Comment: $3a^2 = 4z(2a-z)$ to factor and $4a^2+20z^2=(a+4z)^2$

Comment: So, in my mind, we have $3a^2=8az-4z^2$.  Let's find $z$ by using quadratic formula treating all other numbers *and variables* simply as numbers.  Move to one side: $\color{blue}{4}z^2-\color{blue}{8a}z+\color{blue}{3a^2}=0$.  Blindly use the formula requiring no thought: $z = \dfrac{-(-8a)\pm \sqrt{(-8a)^2-4(4)(3a^2)}}{2(4)}$.  Simplify and conclude.

Comment: Yep, it seems letters intimidate me. Thanks @JMoravitz.

Comment: The point of completing the square is to get rid of the $z^2$ term so the $20z^2$ on the other side is wrong, instead since $4$ is the coefficient near $z^2$ and we're looking at $4z^2-8az+3a^2=(2z-2a)^2-4a^2+3a^2=(2z-2a)^2-a^2=(2z-3a)(2z-a)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$3a^2=8az-4z^2$$ is homogeneous and can be rewritten

$$3=8\frac za-4\left(\frac za\right)^2$$ or

$$3=8w-4w^2.$$

By the classical formula,

$$w=\frac12,\frac32$$ so

$$z=\frac a2,\frac{3a}2.$$